# Error in Fortran 77, reading numbers from a file using 2d arrays

Tags: fortran

I am writing this program in Fortran 77 and I am just trying to read a 3x3 matrix with simple numbers,

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

and then print them to another file.

```
       program filoIO_2darray
       dimension a(3,3)

       open(7,file="text.txt",status="old")
       open(8,file="test1.txt",status="unknown")

       do i=1,3
       do j=1,3
       read(7,*,end=50)a(i,j)
       end do
       end do

50     write(*,"(20(""*****""))")

       do i=1,3
       do j=1,3
       write(*,"(3x,i10)")a(i,j)
       end do
       end do


       pause
       end
```

the output on the screen is very large numbers like

```
1065353216
1073741824
1077936168
   ...
```

and if I put the output on the file then

```
    **
    **
    **
    .0
    .0
    .0
    **
    .0
    .0
```

Comment: What is the exact structure of your input data file?  This code is expecting one number on each line.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour[ We need to see your input file.

Comment: Why are you writing using the `i10` format? Can you confirm it is really that way in your code? What happens when you change `write(*,"(3x,i10)")a(i,j)` to just `write(*,*)a(i,j)` ?

Comment: Maybe also add `implicit none` at the beginning so you see that variables are no declared and take default types (i.e. real for `a` and integer for `i` and `j`)

Answer (score 0):

You can read your 2d array from `text.txt` using implicit do loops in Fortran:

```
      program fileIO_2darray
      dimension k(3,3)

      open(7,file="text.txt",status="old")
      open(8,file="test1.txt",status="unknown")

      read(7,*,end=50) ((k(i,j),j=1,3),i=1,3)

50    write(*,"(20(""*****""))")

      write(*,"(3x,i10)")((k(i,j),j=1,3),i=1,3)

      pause
      end
```

The output looks like:

```
****************************************************************************************************
            1
            2
            3
            4
            5
            6
            7
            8
            9
```

If you want to use implicit variables in Fortran then you have to care about the meaning of the first letter of the variable name:

> `a` ... `h` and `o` ... `z` are type `real`
>
> `i` ... `n` are type `integer`

Please not that Fortran is case insensitive.

As you want to read a matrix composed of `integer` values, the field variable shall start with `i` ... `n`. I've chosen `k`, as `i` and `j` are already taken for the loops.

Hope it helps?